# Запуск файлов через java

Tags: java, файлы

Мне нужно запустить определенный файл (start.bat), через код java. это вообще возможно?

Comment: Да, это возможно.

Comment: Можете уточнить вопрос, что именно вы хотели спросить, возможно ли это или как это запустить?

Answer (score 1):

Да, это возможно. Например, так:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd start start.bat");
```

Где `start.bat` -- полный путь до файла `start.bat`.

Comment: Спасибо!, а что делать в случаи линукса?

Comment: @SCpacker, А причем тут линукс?

Answer (score 1):

Это так же можно сделать через `ProcessBuilder`. К сожалению, не могу точно сказать как это будет для `Windows`, но на `Mac` выполнение команды, например `ls -i` в терминале будет выглядеть так:

```
    String[] command = new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", "ls", "-i"};
    ProcessBuilder probuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = probuilder.start();

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(line);
    }

    try {
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        if (exitCode != 0) System.out.println("error code is not zero");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Думаю, по аналогии сможете подставить те команды, которые вам требуются.